# MediaRecorder setAudioSource failed -- App Crashes (possibly due to CM13)

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception, mediarecorder

I followed a video tutorial to write this code. I get a `java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed` error that causes `Unable to start activity`

I am debugging on a 1st Gen Moto G with Cyanogenmod 13 installed. 
My assumption is that my custom ROM has a conflict with MediaRecorder. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I should also mention that I have the correct permissions in AndroidManifest

```
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private String outputFile = null;
    private Button start, stop, play;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(false);
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myrec.3pg";

        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

    }

    public void start(View v) {
        try {
            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
            myAudioRecorder.start();
        } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        start.setEnabled(false);
        stop.setEnabled(true);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void stop(View v) {
        myAudioRecorder.stop();
        myAudioRecorder.release();
        myAudioRecorder = null;
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Audio recorded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void play(View v) throws IOException {
        MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
        m.setDataSource(outputFile);
        m.prepare();
        m.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Playing Audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**UI / XML Editor**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.m4db0x.freestylerapdisorder.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/recording_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_audio_online"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:text="@string/start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="stop"
        android:text="@string/stop" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="play"
        android:text="@string/play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

May be its too late but hope it would be helpful for someone...

Try to Change in your device 
settings > privacy and safety > App Permission.

Try giving the required permission there too. Permission given in the device takes higher ranking than in the code.

That helped me out.

Comment: This did not immediately solve my problem. But I made progress.